# Triple integral using substitution method, boundary check

Tags: multivariable-calculus, solution-verification, multiple-integral

> Please check my substitution for this integral,
> $$\iiint _V\left(x^2+z^2\right)\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y\,\mathrm{d}z,$$
> where $z=x^2+y^2$, $z\in\left[2,4\right]$.

I am not sure how to do the correct substitution, this is how I've done it since $z=x^2+y^2$ its a paraboloid:

$$x=\rho \cos\theta,\quad y=\rho \sin\theta,$$

where $\rho \in \left[\sqrt{2},2\right]$, $\theta \in \left[0,2\pi \right]$, $z\in \left[2,4\right]$.

No need to evaluate the integral, I just wanna check if I did the boundary right.

Comment: What you have are constants for all of the boundaries, that is the first sign it is not correct. Constant boundaries in spherical coordinates would look like spheres, cones, or special planes (xy plane and all planes exactly perpendicular to xy plane)

Comment: @NinadMunshi I really don't know how to find them, I tried using the cylindric coordinates as well and I got $h \in \left[\rho,1\right]$, $\theta \in \left[0,2\pi \right]$,$\rho\in \left[2,4\right]$, but I am not sure either about this one...

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are using cylindrical coordinates. No the bounds are not correct. These bounds will give you volume between two cylinders of radii $\sqrt2 \ $ and $ \ 2$ of height $2$.

Also bounds depend on the order of the integral. So always specify that.

In cylindrical coordinates, if we are going in the order $dr$ first and then $dz$ and $d\theta$,

We have $z = x^2 + y^2 = r^2 \implies r = \sqrt z$ on paraboloid surface. So

$0 \leq r \leq \sqrt z$

$2 \leq z \leq 4$ and $0 \leq \theta \leq 2\pi$.

Comment: I see, no I didn't use the cylindrical coordinates at first I didn't think about it and then I tried to use them yes, thanks as usual!